# Unmet dependencies after skype

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, skype

I tried install Skype from deb-file, downloaded from Skype.com on my fresh Ubuntu 14.04.

This attepmt caused an error:

```
...
 skype depends on libasound2-plugins.

dpkg: error processing package skype (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
...
```

OK, I decided to live skype for now - and install other packages (`screen`, `vim` etc).

But - apt-get again says about skype:

```
# apt-get install screen
...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 skype:i386 : Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.3.6-6~) but it is not going to be installed
...
```

How can I remove this from dpkg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correct the unmet dependencies and install them, use the command which it gives:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Then it should allow you to use Skype and to install other software.

Or if you have decided that you don't want Skype then just run:

```
sudo apt-get purge skype
```

And that should remove Skype and the error.

Comment: Thanks. I just long time don't used Debian/Ubuntu (on servers I have CentOS basically). And today decided to install Ubuntu on my laptop - and it's started from such problems >.< So I was confused a little bit :-)